# Does macOS Server 5 support permanent version storage?

Tags: osx-server, versions

2012-08-13: [OS X Server: "The document 'file name' is on a volume that does not support permanent version storage" alert](http://web.archive.org/web/20130112045719/http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4218) (affected: Lion Server, OS X Server (Mountain Lion))

2014-11-14: [OS X Server: "The document 'file name' is on a volume that does not support permanent version storage" alert - Apple Support](http://web.archive.org/web/20141129071540/http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203598) – HT203598

2016-07-26: HT203598 [has been archived and is no longer updated by Apple](https://web.archive.org/web/20170119182830/https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203598).

I can find nothing current, from Apple, about *either* the absence *or* the presence of support for permanent version storage in its most recent Server product for Mac OS X.

Has macOS Server gained support for permanent version storage?

Or is there simply no current support document about the absence of support?

Comment: The support article is specifically talking about lack of permanent version storage on network connected drives. All local HFS+ drives support permanent version storage (according to your link).